# Can't use tc in docker container

Tags: permissions, docker, containers, network-traffic, netlink

I am using tc to limit send rate in a docker container.
Added below script into Dockerfile:

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 2
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:2 htb rate 2mbit ceil 2mbit prio 2
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:2 handle 2: sfq perturb 10
tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1:0 u32 match ip dst 192.168.1.124 flowid 1:2
```

Run docker under root account via this command:

```
docker run --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --name lqt_build -d -p 8443:8443 -p 443:443 -p 3478:3478 lqt_build
```

But it still show this error:

```
Step 25 : RUN cd /usr/share/ta/ && sudo ./tt rate
---> Running in fb6a4477ad6c
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
RTNETLINK answers: Operation not permitted
We have an error talking to the kernel
[8] System error: read parent: connection reset by peer
```

It seems the kernel prevents apps in the container from changing some kernel settings even though they're running as root. I guess the container doesn't have its own kernel but runs on the kernel shared with (potentially) many other containers so it can't be allowed to touch settings of the underlying kernel. Does anyone have experience with this issue?

Comment: it seems you just modify the network card of the container from the host, see https://github.com/ahervieu/Docker-Cgroup-Doc

Comment: Thanks. I found the root cause.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root cause is the use of tc in Dokcerfile. NET_ADMIN capability does not take effect at that time. Tc command works fine after docker container is running. Thanks user2915097.